# Will a mail to the journal asking about the status of my article have a negative effect on the decision of the article?

Tags: publications, journals, journal-workflow

One of my journal article was submitted to a journal last year. It has been under review for more than 3 months now. I want to send them a mail asking for my article status. It is given in the website of the journal that the average time for first decision after the article goes under review is 8.5 week. Is there a chance that this mail may affect the journals decision, like they may think that I am being pushy and might just not even go through the paper and reject it?

Comment: It will probably not have any true negative effect, but if 3 months is not considered long in your field, then writing to ask already might make you look like you are not familiar with how things work, which could give the editor a slightly negative impression of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It most likely won't. I think it is normal to push the editor if there is a significant delay. Check what the average time for receiving reviews is first.

I have done it when there has been a significant delay and it hasn't been a problem.

Comment: As a former EIC (the one who'd be contacted regarding a decision), I have to push back on this.  It is normal to push the editor (or publication staff, preferably) if there is an *inordinate* delay.  Here, if the average time to first decision is 8.5 weeks, that probably means X% are rejected without review very quickly and (100-X)% are reviewed over the period of 3 months or more.  It is too soon to be pushy.

Comment: Thank you Fred Douglis, I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -3):

Usually , three months needed for a journal to find a reviewer, collect their opinion on your paper and make decision. Afterward if you didn't receive news , you need to ask about the status of your article .

Comment: Review and processing times vary so much between fields that this answer is at best misleading without specifying the field.